# display tooltip when you hover something that is not a control

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I'm working on a calendar and I'd like to add a tooltip on the control when I hover an item on the calendar. Like other windows form calendars, my calendar has an item which could be used to indicate an appointment. I looked online on how to display a tooltip and I believe this is one way of doing it. Including this method:

```
toolTip1.Show("string to display", controlCalendar1);
```

The first parameter is the text to display when you hover the mouse onto an item and the second parameter is the control you hover the mouse onto. The problem is that I want to hover it on an item in the calendar control and not the actual calendar control.

Thanks in advance

The calendar control i am using is this one which i found online:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252247/Calendar-Planner

Comment: Just update tooltip's text on your Calendar's MouseMove event handler. Tooltip will be associated with the calendar (it works only with controls) but its text will change according to "non control" hovered item.

Comment: which item do you want to add tooltip?

Comment: @Adriano I dont fully understand what you are trying to say. What is the right method to show tooltip? is the one i posted above?

Comment: @rajeem an item on the calendar. the calendar control i am using is the one i found online:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252247/Calendar-Planner?msg=4623178#xx4623178xx

as you see there are items on the calendar which is a WeekPlannerItem object.

Comment: If you're using the control in the link you posted just attach an handler to **ItemMouseHover** and how your tooltip there.

Comment: @majik27 your problem depends much on the custom control, I don't think there is a complete solution for you, just suggestion.

Comment: ToolTip.Show() has a bunch of overloads.  Including ones that take a Point, it lets you position the tip where you want it.

Comment: @HansPassant his problem is not how to show a tooltip at a certain point but when to show it, his custom control is some kind of composited control (a black box to many people here), he wants his tooltip to be shown when mouse is over a certain part of that composited custom control, which is not easy I think so.

Comment: @KingKing My question is if theres a way to show a tooltip when you hover a non-control

Comment: @majik27 but the control from the link you gave in `codeproject` is a `CONTROL`, there is not anything like `non-control` which can be interactive,

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed, thanks to Hans Passant!

you can use your mouse position

```
    toolTip1.Show(tooltipstring, this, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, 1000);
```